# React Native Expo Firestore onSnapshot function not working on iOS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to implement live update subscription to a document reference in firestore. I am using firebase/firestore, since react-native-firestore is not compatible with Expo.
The issue I am having is that it works fine when run on the web using Expo, but does not work when run on iOS using Expo. When run on iOS using Expo, it does not reach the console.log("Current data") statement.

```
onSnapshot(await doc(firestore, "users", user.uid), (doc) => {
    console.log("Current data");

    if (doc.data()) {
        const oData = {
            likedMovies: doc.data().likedMovies,
            dislikedMovies: doc.data().dislikedMovies,
            matches: doc.data().likedMovies // TODO: change this to matches array
        }

        setUserData(oData)
    } else {
        setUserData({})
    }
})
```

I get this warning:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Like I said, it works perfectly in web (Chrome) but does not work at all on iOS.

I tried making it asynchronous, and it stopped the app from crashing on iOS, but it never reaches the setUserData part or it is set to undefined.

I am assuming it should be something to do with the onSnapshot function, but it's strange that it works in Chrome but not iOS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error messages, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code). ---

Comment: Posting it as text also gives you a chance to search for the error message, as I'm pretty sure this has come up before and is like caused by `user.uid` being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

try to hunt the cause as below ,but please 1st read the point raised by the @FrankvanPuffelen .

then approach to below block.

```
onSnapshot(await doc(firestore, "users", user.uid), (doc) => {
  console.log("Current data");
  //if(doc.data().likedMovies==null||doc.data().dislikedMovies==null|| doc.data().likedMovie==null){
    console.log('somthing could be null here chack 1. likedMovies:'+doc.data().likedMovies+' 2. dislikedMovies :'+doc.data().dislikedMovies+ '3. likedMovie'+doc.data().likedMovie)
  //}
  if (doc.data()) {
   
    const oData = {
      likedMovies: doc.data().likedMovies ?? [],
      dislikedMovies: doc.data().dislikedMovies ?? [],
      matches: doc.data().matches ?? [],
    }

      setUserData(oData)
  } else {
      setUserData({})
  }
})
```